# imwrite error during looping in matlab

Tags: matlab

Im newbie in Matlab and I have a problem to saving my processed images.
So here is the command to do segmentation, cropping my images and save it in the specific path

Run.m

```
   Images_Number_Train=length(Input_Images);
   Urutan=1;
   for loop1=1:Images_Number_Train
   Images=imread(Input_Images(loop1));
   Label_Images=Label_Train(loop1);
   Sign = Crop_Sign(Images);
   Order= Save_Crop(Sign,Label_Images,Urutan);
   Urutan=Order;
   end
```

Save function

```
   function Urutan = Save_Crop(Sign,Label_Images,Urutan)

   Output_Path = 'E:\Images\Crop\Train\';
   if ~exist(Output_Path, 'dir')
   mkdir(Output_Training_Path);
   end
   newimagename = [Output_Path 'Images_Crop_' num2str(Urutan) '.pgm'];
   imwrite(Sign,newimagename);
   Urutan=Urutan+1;
   end
```

I have 120 Images and everytime I run the command, This program only can read images until 30 and then stop..

I got this error messege:

```
      Error using imwrite (line 421)
      Expected DATA to be nonempty.

      Error in Save_Crop (line 24)
      imwrite(Sign,newimagename);
```

and the value of Sign variable will be (after images 30th)

```
 val =

   Empty array: 0-by-0-by-3
```

Any suggestion, what I have to do

Comment: For the function `Save_Crop`, at the end of it use this - `Urutan_Train = Urutan_Train+1`. Or just change the function declaration as - `function Urutan = Save_Crop(Sign,Label_Images,Urutan)`. Not sure if this will sort out your issue, but this looked like a bug.

Comment: I have changed it, but still same error

Comment: Doing something unexpected in `Crop_Sign` for images after the 30th one it seems. Look into that function and those images.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you actually have an empty image in there. (It has 0x0x3==0 elements).

If you don't think this is the case, make sure to carefully inspect your data. Otherwise, if you just want to skip it, wrap part of your code with an `if` statement like this:

```
if(~isempty(Images))
   %Do stuff
end
```